# Mosquitto Broker - Can still sign in with no credentials after allow_anonymous set to false

Tags: windows, authentication, mqtt, mosquitto, broker

Following Steve Copes "How to install the Mosquitto Broker on Windows",  I created a password.txt file and encrypted it using the mosquiito_passwd utility.

Then I edited the mosquitto.conf file by uncommenting allow_anonymous and setting to false, and uncommenting password_file and setting the path of my password.txt file (In the same folder as mosquitto.conf)

Using MQTT Explorer I am able to log into the broker using the credentials in my password.txt file, but I am also able to still log in leaving user and password blank.

I've seen similar questions being asked here, but I can't find any solutions that have worked, please point me in the right direction. I'am using mosquitto 2.0.14 x64 on Windows 10

Edit:

Only edit done to mosquitto.conf is uncommenting the lines as follows:

```
# acl_file
allow_anonymous false
# allow_zero_length_clientid
# auto_id_prefix
password_file C:\Users\'MyName'\mosquitto\password.txt
# plugin
# plugin_opt_*
# psk_file
```

Comment: Did you restart mosquitto after you edited the configuration? Also, please edit the question to include the configuration files and the mosquitto log file.

Comment: Hi Romkey thanks for the reply, I did restart mosquitto, also I've editted in the changes I've made to mosquitto.conf, there is no log file that's been generated. I will work on that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution Found:
Adding 'listener 1883' before allow_anonymous false has got it working although I am unsure why that makes a difference.
Config file as follows:

```
# acl_file
listener 1883
allow_anonymous false
# allow_zero_length_clientid
# auto_id_prefix
password_file C:\Users\'MyName'\mosquitto\password.txt
# plugin
# plugin_opt_*
# psk_file
```

Comment: Legend! Added the same to resolve my version of the problem, raspbian/raspberrypi OS. I imagine it's a bug and should be filed. That listener value is a default so should be unnecessary IMHO

Comment: This was savior!!

Comment: Fix worked with Ubuntu 23.04. Weird issue.